# Как правильно перемешать вывод запроса

Tags: laravel

Есть две таблицы
`prods`

```
id|site_id|title|category_id
```

`sites`

```
id|title|rating
```

И запрос

```
$prod= Prod::where('category_id', $category->id)
  ->join('sites as po', function($join) {
    $join->on('po.id', '=', 'prods.site_id');
  })->orderBy('po.rating', 'desc');
$prod->paginate(20);
```

Тут мы получаем товар с выбранной категорией и сайт который привязан к данному товару и сортируем по рейтингу сайтов

Выводит:

```
Название товара 1 - Сайт 1
Название товара 2 - Сайт 1
Название товара 3 - Сайт 2
Название товара 4 - Сайт 2
Название товара 5 - Сайт 2
```

*У сайта 2 рейтинг меньше

Встала задача еще отсортировать таким образом, чтобы сайты не повторялись подряд, чтобы чередовались

Пробовал использовать `inRandomOrder()`:

```
$prod= Prod::where('category_id', $category->id)
  ->join('sites as po', function($join) {
    $join->on('po.id', '=', 'prods.site_id');
  })->orderBy('po.rating', 'desc');
$prod->inRandomOrder()->paginate(20);
```

Выводит:

```
Название товара 1 - Сайт 1
Название товара 2 - Сайт 2
Название товара 3 - Сайт 1
Название товара 4 - Сайт 2
Название товара 5 - Сайт 2
Название товара 6 - Сайт 1
```

Но, все равно встречаются повтора подряд, как полностью избежать повторов подряд и при этом оставить сортировку по рейтингу(+-)

И получить такой вид:

```
Название товара 1 - Сайт 1
Название товара 2 - Сайт 2
Название товара 3 - Сайт 1
Название товара 4 - Сайт 2
Название товара 5 - Сайт 1
Название товара 6 - Сайт 3
```

Рейтинг:

```
Сайт 1 - 5 баллов
Сайт 2 - 4 баллов
Сайт 3 - 1 баллов
```

СУБД - MySQL 5.7.24-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 - (Ubuntu)

Comment: С  точки зрения SQL надо, видимо, сортировать по `row_number() over (partition by site), site.rating`. Как это выглядит в laravel - я лично фиг знает (да и знает ли твой сервер про оконные функции? если нет- придётся эмулировать). PS. СУБД бы указать, включая версию.

Comment: *И получить такой вид* А почему не `1,2,6,3,4,5` (товары), чтобы `1,2,3,1,2,1` (сайты)?

Comment: @Akina Подправил вопрос, цифры в названии у товара указал, чтобы показать, что это разные товары). `чтобы 1,2,3,1,2,1 (сайты)` нужно еще оставить сортировку по рейтингу, у сайта 3 самый маленький рейтинг, значит он должен быть ниже

Comment: @РустамГимранов Моя ошибка не досмотрел при копировании кода в вопрос, подправил вопрос.

Comment: *цифры в названии у товара указал* Ихде?

Comment: Отношения в модели не используются, подправил вопрос